# show and count not working pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to create a pyspark dataframe and it shows the schema as well post creation.
Below is the code I am using to create a dataframe:

```
data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
```

It prints the schema but I get following error while trying to do count.
Similarly I am unable to do show as well, it although prints schema

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-35c0d674a0ad> in <module>
          1 df.cache()
          2 print('cache done')
    ----> 3 df.count()
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in count(self)
        662         2
        663         """
    --> 664         return int(self._jdf.count())
        665 
        666     def collect(self):
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
       1304         return_value = get_return_value(
    -> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1306 
       1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
        109     def deco(*a, **kw):
        110         try:
    --> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
        112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
        113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
        326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
        327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
        329             else:
        330                 raise Py4JError(
```

Comment: can you try without the `df,cache()`

Comment: could you show more about about the error log?

Comment: please share the full error traceback, if able